# «Керчь: забыть невозможно, помнить — больно». Пунктуация в заголовке

Tags: пунктуация, тире-или-двоеточие, заголовок

Правильно ли стоит двоеточие в заголовке?
**Керчь: забыть невозможно, помнить — больно**
Или достаточно точки? Или тире?

Comment: Цитата без завершающей точки. Тире выглядит дефисом. «Достаточно точки» — это как же и где же?

Comment: @shampar Имелся в виду **заголовок** без завершающей точки. Вопрос о знаке после слова Керчь. Дефис я исправил на тире. Думаю, теперь можно не закрывать вопрос, если нет других замечаний.

Comment: @grizzly Я "поправила" вопрос ещё раз (надеюсь, Вы не против). Так, мне кажется, теперь всем всё понятно. Неплохой ведь вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На мой взгляд, точка — наиболее подходящий вариант, хотя и двоеточие допустимо.

**Керчь. Забыть невозможно, помнить — больно**

Советую ознакомиться с тем, что пишет Розенталь:
[Раздел 16. ЗНАКИ ПРЕПИНАНИЯ В ГАЗЕТНЫХ И ЖУРНАЛЬНЫХ ЗАГОЛОВКАХ](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=168)

В частности:

> 2. Двоеточие ставится в заголовках, распадающихся на две части с четким интонационным делением, отличающихся смысловой насыщенностью, предельной краткостью и нередко эмоциональной выразительностью. Первая часть называет общую проблему, место действия, лицо, а вторая — содержит конкретизацию названного в первой части:
>
> Экономическая реформа: опыт, проблемы, трудности; Разоружение: концепция, проблемы, механизм; Россия — Западная Европа: выгоды и перспективы сотрудничества; Звёздный рейс: работа на отлично!; Новый герой: поиски и находки; Женщина: семья и работа; Юпитер: планета или звезда?; Перевозка айсбергов: мифы и реальность; Смена правительства: старое наследство, новые возможности; Генетика: стратегия и тактика; Космические лучи: старые или новые?; Энергетика: начало и будущее; Многоэтажные улицы: спасение или бедствие?; Рентгеновский лазер: поиски и надежды.
>
> 6. Точка ставится:
>      1) в сегментированных заголовках [см. § 1, п. 4]:
>      Кольца Сатурна. Какие они?;
>      Два выходных. Как их лучше использовать?;
>      Лесные десантники. Где их готовят?;
>      Эстрада. Она всегда волнует

Дополнение
А велосипед-то, оказывается, уже изобрели:
[Керчь. Забыть невозможно, помнить - больно](http://www.dumrf.ru/common/opinions/14485)

Comment: К сожалению, ЭТОТ "велосипед" иногда сбоит.

Answer (score 3):

Знаки препинания при именительном темы http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?rid=63

Оба варианта возможны.

Керчь. Забыть невозможно, помнить — больно.

Керчь: забыть невозможно, помнить — больно.

http://dumrf.ru/common/opinions/14485

Именительный падеж отделяется знаками препинания, соответствующими концу предложения, — точкой, восклицательным знаком, вопросительным знаком, многоточием. Каждый знак вносит соответствующий смысловой и эмоциональный оттенок.

Примечание.  Допустимо используемое в практике печати и написание со знаком двоеточие: Студенческий быт: каким ему быть? (газ.).